# PXE Boot Server stalling with "File not found" error

Tags: 10.04, server, dhcp, pxe, tftp

I'm trying to setup my Ubuntu 10.04 Server to allow PXE booting for the clients in my lab. I have configured the DHCP settings and everything, and I boot up my client, and it sits at a screen similar to the following:

```
CLIENT MAC ADDR: 00 01 80 5F 9A 79  GUID: 00000000 0000 0000 0000 000000000001
CLIENT IP: 192.168.0.128  MASK: 255.255.255.0  DHCP IP: 192.168.0.100
GATEWAY IP: 192.168.0.100
_
```

Before, I was getting the wonderful "PXE- T01 File not found" error, but now it just stalls. I checked the syslog on my server, and it gives me the following info:

```
dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:01:80:5f:9a:79 via eth1
dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.0.128 to 00:01:80:5f:9a:79 via eth1
dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.128 (192.168.0.100) from 00:01:80:5f:9a:79 via eth1
dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.0.128 to 00:01:80:5f:9a:79 via eth1
in.tftpd[2371]: tftp: client does not accept options
```

Not quite sure what is going on here. I looked up the whole "client does not accept options", however most places I find say to ignore it. I still have the problem of stalling, however.

Here is my dhcpd.conf file:

```
ddns-update-style none;
authoritative;
allow booting;
allow bootp;

option domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

log-facility local7;

subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.254
    option domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222;
    option routers 192.168.0.100;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;

    default-lease-time 600;
    max-lease-time 7200;

    next-server 192.168.0.100;
    filename "pxelinux.0";
}
```

I have been using this tutorial, by the way:

http://www.serenux.com/2010/05/howto-setup-your-own-pxe-boot-server-using-ubuntu-server/

If there is anymore information I can provide that could be of assistance, please inform me and I will provide it.

Thank you in advance for all of your help

Comment: Firewall disabled?
Please post cat /var/log/messages | grep dhcpd

Comment: It'll take a few days. We are on Spring Break and the building's power is being shut off for a day. Once it is back on I will have my professor turn the server back on and check it out.

Comment: Sorry for the large delay in response. Here is one of the results from the file:
dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:01:80:5f:9a:79 from eth1
    dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.0.128 to 00:01:80:5f:9a:79 via eth1
    dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.128 (192.168.0.100) from 00:01:80:5f:9a:79 via eth1
    dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.0.128 to 00:01:80:5f:9a:79 via eth1

Comment: @Meddy Does this information help? Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem: The pxelinux.0 file did not copy over correctly. There must have been an error when I was downloading the CD, as when I looked through all of the files, the pxelinux.0 file was empty.